# Response object coming back as < number number number etc> from JSON request

Tags: swift, swift3, stripe-payments

Im making a request to stripe and getting a response back but cant seem to read the object as its coming back as:

```
<43686172 67652073 75636365 73736675 6c6c7920 63726561 746564>
```

my code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func registerAccountButtonWasPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    let dob = self.dobTextField.text!.components(separatedBy: "/")
    let URL = "https://splitterstripeservertest.herokuapp.com/account/create"
    let params = [
        "first_name": firstNameTextField.text!,
        "last_name": lastNameTextField.text!,
        "line1": addressLine1TextField.text!,
        "city": cityTextField.text!,
        "postal_code": postCodeTextField.text!,
        "country": countryTextField.text!,
        "day": UInt(dob[0])! as UInt,
        "month": UInt(dob[1])! as UInt,
        "year": UInt(dob[2])! as UInt] as [String : Any]

    let serializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
    serializer.stringEncoding = String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
    manager.requestSerializer = serializer
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()

    manager.post(URL, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: {(_ task: URLSessionDataTask, _ responseObject: Any) -> Void in
        print(responseObject)
        if let response = responseObject as? [String: Any] {
            UIAlertView(title: response["status"] as! String?,
                        message: response["message"] as! String?,
                        delegate: nil,
                        cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
            print(response)
        }
    }, failure: {(_ task: URLSessionDataTask?, _ error: Error) -> Void in
        self.handleError(error as NSError)
    })
}
```

Can anyone see what im doing wrong or need to do to read the reponse as a useful dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: It's treating that field as NSData, if I had to guess

Comment: yea, it was, just figured it out thanks, ill post an answer in a minute